# Microsoft visual studio 2008 error c2143 , c2059

Tags: visual-c++

I have Symbol.h and Symbol.cpp working perfectly in a separate project

now I need to include it in a yacc file , that gives error c2143 , c2059

any idea what the problem can be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you should include offending source code in you question to get more helpful answers.

From which file those error happen? The yacc c/cpp file? or Symbol.cpp?

May be, macros defined in the yacc file are conflict with Symbol.h.

First check include order.

You could use /P compiler option. Resulting .i file will show plain source code with all the macros expanded.